# $f is undefined for Flowplayer instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, rtmp, flowplayer

Below is the code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/flowplayer.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a style="display: block;height:400px;width:600px;background-color: #ffffff;border: solid 1px #ccc;" id="fms"></a>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $f("fms", "flowplayer/flowplayer.swf", {
        clip: {
            url: 'livestream',
            live: true,
            provider: 'rtmp'
        },

        plugins: {
            rtmp: {
                url: 'flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.12.swf',
                netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://myserver.com/live'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

When I try to run this I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $f is not defined" as an error.  Everything seems to be loading correctly.  The flowplayer files were installed locally, but I tested linking directly (the same is true with for the jQuery file). In addition, I changed the location of the $f file to no avail. Nothing has seemed to work.  Any guidance?

Comment: i'm having same problem right now

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is the flowplayer script is definitely downloading.

If it is then it sounds like your JavaScript code is executing before your flowplayer script has finished.  Try wrapping your code with `jQuery(document).ready();`

**Example**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    $f("fms", "flowplayer/flowplayer.swf", {
        clip: {
            url: 'livestream',
            live: true,
            provider: 'rtmp'
        },

        plugins: {
            rtmp: {
                url: 'flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.12.swf',
                netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://myserver.com/live'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using $f make sure you have included the Flowplayer Javascript API, as this is a separate file from the main flowplayer js include

Answer (score 0):

use "flowplayer" instead of $f

```
flowplayer("fms", "flowplayer/flowplayer.swf", {
    clip: {
        url: 'livestream',
        live: true,
        provider: 'rtmp'
    },

    plugins: {
        rtmp: {
            url: 'flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.12.swf',
            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://myserver.com/live'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

It should just be `$(`, not `$f(`

Also, `"language=javascript"` is deprecated and no longer needed.

Comment: No, $f() is shorthand for flowplayer(), provided by the flowplayer javascript libraries - it's nothing to do with jquery.